# Does VS Code have a "Project Explorer" feature like Eclipse's?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, project, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse C/C++ to VScode, the next missing thing is Project Explorer:

[image]

Seems like VScode only allows one project to be open:

[image]

How can I turn on multi project mode, activating projects individually (open/close projects)?

Comment: the alternative is **Multi Root Workspace**